# How to write the method definition for a recursive function?

Tags: c++, data-structures

Printer_Helper is a recursive function that prints the contents of a linked list.

```
struct Node
{
    string data;
    Node *next;
}

void List::print() 
{
    Print_Helper(head);
}
```

How to write the method definition for a recursive function?

Comment: With a base case and a recursive call? There are lots of examples of recursive functions to use for help.

Comment: What have you tried? Just asking how to do something or asking for code is discouraged here. But if you show what you tried and where your problem is, you'll probably get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically recursion works like this:

- You have a problem (printing a node)
- part of the problem is to solve the same problem for a smaller part of the curent one (printing the child nodes)
- at some point no smaller problem exists and you can stop solving (no more child nodes)

In this case it works like:

```
print content of current node
if there are any child nodes:
    for each child node:
        call this function with the child node
```